# How to inject an object that is not a ViewModel to a composable function?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

In my first composable I would like to check if the user has logged in or not, in order to decide the navigation destination. To know this, I have a very simple class, named `AppPrefs` that uses `SharedPreferences` to know the state of logged in. In any class I create, I can dome something like this:

```
class SomeClassIMade {
    @Inject
    lateinit var appPrefs: AppPrefs

    fun f() {
        var isLoggedIn: Boolean = appPrefs.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

Or I can inject `AppPrefs` in the constructor. This all works fine.

However, I would like to get a hold of an `AppPrefs` object inside a composable function, i.e.:

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navHostController = rememberNavController()
    // here I would like to inject an object of a class that I have created
}
```

I have tried to find the answer but it seems that the only thing that can be injected here is a `ViewModel` using a call to `androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel`.

Is what I am trying to achieve impossible? Or perhaps not a good practice?

The only "work-around" I can think of is to:

1. Create a new `ViewModel` and inject it in my `Navigation` composable function
2. Inject an `AppPrefs` object in my new `ViewModel`
3. Write simple functions/methods in my new `ViewModel` that expose the `AppPrefs`'s functions/methods to the `Navigation` composable function

But I can't help but think that is not a very good way to achieve my goal, hence why I am asking the question in the first place.

Comment: can you not have the dependecy class in viewmodel or activity and pass it to the compose function? You have 3 options like already mentioned.  3rd one looks good. AppPrefs in separat and ou can use it in viewmodel and expose it to compose functions.